# Kubernetes multiple environment variables per environment using Helm 3 go template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have 2 different values.yaml files per stage and production environment such as values.dev.yaml > values.prod.yaml and using with Helm 3. I would like to learn the best practices how to pass environment variables per environments.For instance we need to set different parameters to NODE_ENV variable.

-Should I specify the variable as hard coded as below and pass the environment variables when running `helm upgrade/install` command with `--set` flag?

-What is the correct way to use go template to do this. Can we specify something {{ .Values.node_env.value}} and then pass this env value in values yaml and use only -f values.yaml flag?

```
      containers:
            - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
              securityContext:
                {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
              image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
              imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
              ports:
                - name: http
                  containerPort: 8080
                  protocol: TCP
              resources:
                {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
              env: 
              - name: "NODE_ENV"
                value: "stage"
              - name: "NODE_ENV"
                value: "production"
```

Comment: `helm install --set` only sets values in the `.Values` object; it won't override environment variables.  You can use the `helm template` command to see what a chart renders to with a given set of values without actually installing it.  Your last suggestion using `{{ .Values.nodeEnv }}` sounds about right and I'd suggest experimenting with that.

Comment: @DavidMaze, how should I specify nodeEnv in values.yaml ? Any place is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have one value file per environment (it is not clear to me this is your case.) like values.prod.yaml (for prod) and values.dev.yaml (for dev), then your templeate can look like this.

This will cause the template to look for `extraEnv:` in your values{dev/prod}.yaml and iterate over all key/values from that section.

```
  env:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.extraEnv }}
    - name: {{ $key }}
      value: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
```

In your *values.dev.yaml* files you add all your `KEY: values` that are specific for this environment. Note you can have multiple key values here, all of them will be loaded. In this case we have NODE_ENV, ANOTHER_KEY, YET_ANOTHER_KEY - all of them will be loaded.

```
extraEnv:
  NODE_ENV: stage
  ANOTHER_KEY: value
  YET_ANOTHER_KEY: value
```

same in your *values.prod.yaml* multiple `KEY: value` pairs can be specified and all of them will be loaded.

```
extraEnv:
  NODE_ENV: production
  ANOTHER_KEY: value
```

Comment: yes ı ve one value file per environment thanks for your useful response.. by the way ı also have another environment variable what should be the correct format to specify hard coded environment variables and go template together? I just added yours to my question but not sure it is correct

Comment: I have expanded my answer to accommodate your question.

Also,in your template you can have only one `env:` section (per pod), as it is at the moment (after the change you did) your example will confuse other people reading this post in the feature. Please consider changing it back so the question and the answer together make sense.

Comment: should specify the values with quotes due to it is string? when ı run helm template ı could not able to see this NODE _ENV value but able to see rest of key values

Comment: All values get quoted because of `value: {{ $value | quote }}`, but you can try to quote as well.

Comment: Also please read "_you can have only one env: section **(per pod)**_" as "_you can have only one env: section **(per container)**_"